# Python/Tkinter: why does the .get method of IntVar shows same value when clicking different radiobuttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

### Brief overview of the program:

1. When launching script, the dialog window is appearing and asking you to select directory path (class `MyApp`)
2. When selected - one needs to push the "Start Monitoring" button. This action withdraws the main window (`root`) and initializes the container class `FrameContainer` consisting of two frames, namely `PageOne` and `PageTwo` (see corresponding classes).
3. Button `Back Home` on `Page One` should destroy the instance of the class `FrameContainer` and show the dialog window again. This action is achieved using methods `update()` and `deiconify()`.
4. Selection of any of the radio buttons on `Page One` should change the value of variable `rb_indx` - it is achieved using the `get()` method of `IntVar`.

---

### Problems:

- Radio buttons are initialized in wrong way. The `var.set(1)` should highlight the 'var1' button, however in my case are highlighted `var2` and `var3`.
- The `get()` method of `IntVar` does not update the value of the variable `rb_indx` when selecting a radio button. `print rb_indx` always gives 1
- When closing `PageOne` window by the [x] (in corner of the screen), the  dialog window is not appearing, however is expected...

---

### The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    # Python2
    import Tkinter as Tk
    from Tkinter import IntVar
    from tkFileDialog import askdirectory

except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as Tk
    from tkinter import IntVar
    from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

LARGE_FONT=("Verdana", 12)

########################################################################

class FrameContainer(Tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.original_frame = parent   

        Tk.Tk.__init__ (self)
        container = Tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight =1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo): 

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(PageOne)

    def show_frame (self, cont):

        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def onClose(self):

        self.destroy()
        self.original_frame.show()  

class PageOne(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = Tk.Label(self, text="Page One", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1=Tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", command=lambda: controller.onClose())
        button1.pack()

        button2=Tk.Button(self, text="Page Two", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

        def get_button_indx(): 

            global rb_indx
            rb_indx=var.get()
            print rb_indx

        var.set(1)

        names_tuple = ('var1', 'var2', 'var3')

        for col_numb in range (1,len(names_tuple)+1):
            radio = Tk.Radiobutton(self, text=names_tuple[col_numb-1], variable=var, value=col_numb, command=get_button_indx)
            radio.pack()

class PageTwo(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = Tk.Label(self, text="Page Two", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1=Tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", command=lambda: controller.onClose())
        button1.pack()

        button2=Tk.Button(self, text="Page One", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()

class MyApp(object):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.root = parent
        self.root.title("Start page")
        self.frame = Tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()

        def choosedir():   

            global path_usr_var 
            path_usr_var = askdirectory()
            print path_usr_var

        button1 = Tk.Button(self.frame, text="Select Directory", command=choosedir)
        button1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button2 = Tk.Button(self.frame, text="Start Monitoring", command=self.openFrame)
        button2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    def hide(self):
        self.root.withdraw()

    def openFrame(self):
        self.hide()
        firstFrame = FrameContainer(self)

    def show(self):
        self.root.update()
        self.root.deiconify()

########################################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":

    root = Tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")
    var = IntVar()
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Too much code for me to read.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`. An app must have exactly one instance of `Tk`.What is happening is that `var` belongs to the first instance, but you are associating it with radio buttons that belong to the second instance.

If you need multiple windows, create a single root window and then create instances of `Toplevel` for all additional windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Now the radiobuttons works properly. I have changed solely the following lines:

class FrameContainer(Tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.original_frame = parent   
        Tk.Toplevel.__init__ (self) 

The only problem remaining is N3 from the list - when closing PageOne window by the [x] (in corner of the screen), the dialog window (instance of class MyApp) is not appearing, however is expected... Do you have any ideas on how I can bind this action?